# Python, load Excel file to Dictionary

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm losing my mind here. I don't get why it saves only the last row to the dictionary. I want to save the whole excel table to Dictionary so I can group those values by Key(columnName) and then do something with those values so I can access each cell based on the row number.

```
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path

data = {}
data['dict1'] = {}

xlsx_file = Path(Path.home(), 'FormaterPythonUniversity', 'Template.xlsx')


wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx_file) 

# Read the active sheet:
sheet = wb_obj.active


for i, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True)):
    data['Full Name'] = row[0]
    print(row[0])
    data['dict1']['Work email address'] = row[1]
    data['dict1']['Start date'] = row[2]
    data['dict1']['Manager name'] = row[3]
    data['dict1']['Manager email address'] = row[4]
    data['dict1']['Category'] = row[5]
     
print(data)
```

What happens now is that only the last row of the excel file is being stored in this dictionary.

Example Output:

```
{'dict1': {'Work email address': 'smth.@gmail.com', 'Start date': '2021-11-11', 'Manager name': 'Paul Smth', 'Manager email address': 'PaulSmth@gmail.com', 'Category': 'Owner'}, 'Full Name': 'Smth Smth'}
```

Excel spreadsheet I'm using:

[Screen grab of the Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J69I.png)

I do not understand why it doesn't load the whole thing into the dictionary, and just the info from the last row.

Comment: You use a static value to index your hash. With each row the values of the previous row are overwritten

Comment: why you use `xml` in the post title?

Comment: To elaborate on what Ronald said, dictionary keys have to be unique. This is a core principle of dicts. Well, there's a thing called MultiDict, but let's forget that for now.

Comment: @balderman: new Excel files are XML, but I changed the title to be more specific.

Comment: @qamyk, you keep saving rows in the same keys of the dictionary `data['dict1']`. Make `data` a list, and append a series of new dictionaries to it instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, it is rooted in the fact that you are overwriting the value of each key in every iteration of the loop (i.e. corresponding to each spreadsheet row). You may want to try this for each column before the FOR loop:

```
data['Work email address'] = []
```

and then append each newly read row of the sheet to the lists stored in your dictionary. So you'll have something like below in your loop:

```
data['Work email address'].append(row[1])
```

Someone commented correctly, that the above stores everyone's email address in the same list. You may alternatively use one of the approaches below or your own approach to get exactly what you desire.

Alternative approach 1:

You can make a list of dictionaries each containing information of a row in your spreadsheet.

```
data = [] #before the loop
...
data.append({'Full Name': row[0], 'Work email address': row[1]}) #inside the loop
```

Alternative approach 2:

You can make a dictionary of people's name (for example), and attach their info as a list to their corresponding key:

```
data = {} #before the loop
...
#then inside the loop
employeeName = row[0]
data[employeeName] = [row[1], row[2]] # or {'Work email address': row[1], 'Start date': row[2]}
```

Comment: This would put everyone's email address in the same list.

Comment: Thanks. I added alternative approaches. One can hopefully figure out their own desired way of storing the spreadsheet, using the above. (Also the other answer to the question has correctly suggested the full code suggested in my alternative approach 1.)

Answer (score 1):

You are saving each row in the same keys of the dictionary data['dict1']. Make `data` a list, and append a series of new dictionaries to it instead:

```
data = []
for i, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True)):
    rowdict = dict()
    rowdict['Work email address'] = row[1]
    rowdict['Start date'] = row[2]
    # (etc.)
    data.append(rowdict)
```

Done.